# Finding photos on OS X 10.10.4

Tags: macos, photos.app

Ever since I updated my MacBook to OS X 10.10.4 a lot of my current uploaded photos from 2015 (iPhoto) can not be found?
Am I able to get these back?

Comment: Current photos will be probably being imported to Photos app, not iPhoto. Did you check both apps?

Answer (score 1):

Your photos have always been there and look at the picture the old iPhone app folder'll be there.

Try clicking the right mouse button and choose open with iPhoto and find your entire library.